# Cannot create new account without password

Tags: password

Unable to create new account without a password.(Ubuntu 16.04 ) 
OK, so I add a password but it has to be "strong" otherwise it won't take it. 
Awkward , but...
Than the OS always starts with added user. Awkward again.

Isn't the OS little paranoid about personal PC needed passwords?

Let me worry about unauthorized access, shall we?

Comment: It would take the password if using `passwd`.

Comment: Why would you be against having a strong password?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo adduser new_username` in a terminal window.  This will create a new user accepting any kind of password, even if it is 123.  No need for strong passwords there.